# Database not working running tests in Django with PostgreSQL in docker compose

Tags: django, database, postgresql, docker, testing

I hope you are doing well!
I am having a problem. I am trying to run my Django tests inside of my container with docker compose with the command line `sudo docker compose run --rm app sh -c 'python3 manage.py test'`, but I am receiving these logs

[image]

I am not pretty sure what is happening here. I am not noticing something weird in my docker-compose file either. I have tried cleaning the volumes, deleting all the images, and building again just in case I made something wrong through the process but it didn't fix my problem. I will let you know the file just in case.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args: 
      - DEV=true
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py wait_for_db &&
            python manage.py migrate && 
            python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=dev
      - DB_USER=devuser
      - DB_PASS=changeme
    container_name: django_container
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgresql_db
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - dev-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=dev
      - POSTGRES_USER=devuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=changeme


volumes:
  dev-db-data:
```

Comment: The problem is in the part you didn't show us, like the Dockerfile, or the app itself.

Comment: please provide dockerfile